# C++ struct new with memory bad access

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, struct, nodes

I am trying to create node out of the following. When I try with out "int data", I am able to instantiate a new struct member but with another member variables "string name" added, for some reason, I am getting memory leak.

```
 struct node
 {
      string name;
      int data;
      vector<node*> neighbors;


      node(string name, int data, node* neighbor)
      {
           this->name = name;
           this->data = data;
           neighbors.push_back(neighbor);
      }

      explicit node()
      : name(NULL), data(NULL), neighbors(NULL) {}

      explicit node(string name)
      : name(name), data(NULL), neighbors(NULL) {}
 };
```

ANd the following line is where I am getting error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0"

```
 int main() {
      struct node* root = new node(NULL);
      root->name = "root";
      root->data = 10;
```

How come I don't have error with only one member variable, but I do this one more member member variable? Am I missing to initialize something? I think I am doing with constructors above. Please give me some advice.

Thanks,

Comment: That is so wrong, please avoid pointers and do not initialize std::string with NULL. Avoid NULL, use 0 or better nullptr (But not to initialize the std::string!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some errors here :

- Do not initialise `std::string` with NULL. If you want an empty `string`, use the default constructor or `""`,
- When you call `struct node* root = new node(NULL);` you call the constructor `explicit node(string name)` and initialising a string with NULL causes an error,
- Avoid using pointers when it is possible : `struct node* root = new node();` -> `struct node root();`,
- You initialize your `data` member with `NULL` but this is an `integer`. You should initialize it with `0`,
- You initialize your `neighbors` member with `NULL`, but again, it is not a pointer, you can skip it from the *member-initialization-list*, the default constructor will be called,
- Finally, avoid using `NULL`, use `0` or event `nullptr` if your are in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* root = new node(NULL);
```

calls `explicit node(string name)` constructor, which means you pass `NULL` to initialize `string` causes the error. If you want to construct an empty string pass `""`.

```
struct node
{
  string name;
  int data;
  vector<node*> neighbors;

  explicit node(string name)
  : name(name), 
    data(NULL),      //ERROR, data is int type, not pointer
    neighbors(NULL)  //ERROR, not pointer 
    {}  

  explicit node(const std::string& name = "")
  : data(0)  // name,neighbors constructors are implicitly called
```